# Hot-Encoding only on some elements of a column

Tags: python, pandas, feature-extraction, categorical-data, one-hot-encoding

On my dataset I have many columns with mixed categorical and numerical values. Basically when the numerical value was not available, a code is assigned, like 'M', 'C', etc.. associated to the reason it was missing.
They have special meaning and peculiar behavior, so I want to cast them as categorical, and keep the rest as numeric.
Minimal example:

```
# Original df
ex1 = ['a', 'b', '0', '1', '2']
df = pd.DataFrame(ex1, columns=['CName'])
print(df)

CName
0     a
1     b
2     0
3     1
4     2

## What I want to achieve
df['CName_a'] = (df.CName == 'a').astype(int)
df['CName_b'] = (df.CName == 'b').astype(int)
ff = (df.CName == 'b') | (df.CName == 'a')
df['CNname_num'] = np.where(ff, np.NaN, df.CName)
df2 = df.drop('CName', axis=1)
print(df2)

   CName_a  CName_b CNname_num
0        1        0        NaN
1        0        1        NaN
2        0        0          0
3        0        0          1
4        0        0          2
```

**Question 1**.
Q1: How this can be done efficiently? Ideally I need to chain it in a Pipeline, some fit_transform kind ot thing? I have to write from scratch or there is a hack from common libraries to hot-encode a subset of a column, like ['a', 'b', 'else'] ?

**Question 2**.
Q2: How should I fill the 'Nan' for the CName_num? The categorical elements ('a' and 'b' in the example) have behavior that differ from the average of the numerical (actually from any of the numerical). I feel assign 0 or 'mean' is not the right choice, but I ran out of options. I plan to use Random Forest, DNN, or even Regression-like training if it performs decently.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one potential solution. First create a boolean mask using [`str.isdigit`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.isdigit.html). Use [`pandas.get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) and [`pandas.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) for your final DataFrame:

```
mask = mask = df['CName'].str.isdigit()

pd.concat([pd.get_dummies(df.loc[~mask, 'CName'], prefix='CName')
             .reindex(df.index).fillna(0),
           df.loc[mask].add_suffix('_num')], axis=1)
```

[out]

```
   CName_a  CName_b CName_num
0      1.0      0.0       NaN
1      0.0      1.0       NaN
2      0.0      0.0         0
3      0.0      0.0         1
4      0.0      0.0         2
```

Comment: @jezrael ah, thank you, that is better. will update